# How to fill array or arraylist sequentially without loop?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, fill

I'm surprised I haven't found an answer to this anywhere. I want to fill an int array of 100 with 1..100. Fill is a good method but it doesn't increment the value each turn. Its obvious how to do it with a loop but I want to avoid that due to my maximum value being extremely high. Is there any api method which can do this for me?

Comment: Any API method you use will use a loop internally.
Also, why do you want to fill an ArrayList with 1 to 100 in sequence?

Comment: What do you mean by "my maximum value being extremely high" ?

Comment: Even fill? So using fill to put all 1's in my array or making a loop to put all 1's in my array is equal performance?

Comment: @PrashantSingh It's a variable so it might be 1 to n. So I was seeing if there was anything more efficient than me making a loop run n times.

Comment: Just as a side note, maybe you can do without the array in the first place. Depends on the problem though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. There is no method in the standard library that will do this.
2. Even if there was, it would need to use a loop under the hood.
3. I don't see the significance of *"my maximum value being extremely high"*.  That should make no difference to the decision to use a loop ... or not.
4. Don't use recursion.  Java does not implement tail call optimization so 1) it will be slower than using a loop and 2) you risk getting `StackOverflowError` if the array or list is large.  (Yes, I know it is not large in the question as asked ...)

Comment: I thought the api would be more efficient in filling my array than my loop would. But I guess a loop is a loop no matter where it is.

Comment: +1 A loop is the most efficient, regardless of the language.  For languages which use other approach, they are often compiled down to use a loop for you. e.g. tail recursion can be converted to a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ooooh, use recursion!

```
void to100(int[] array, int i, int v) {
    if( i < array.length ) {
        array[i] = v;
        to100( i+1, v+1 );
    }
}

int[] array = new int[100];

too100( array, 0, 1 );
```

enjoy.

Comment: I have a feeling this will be worse than a loop performance wise (from all the function calls), but you get points for sarcasm xD

Comment: It would be:

`int[] hit = new int[100];
 to100(hit, 1, hit.length);
 
 static void to100(int[] array, int i, int v) 
 {
     if( i < 100 ) 
     {
         array[i] = i;
         to100(array, i+1,v+1);
     }
 }`